# onchange collection getting error not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to listen to onChange event to collection and getting error:

> Uncaught TypeError: listSongs.on is not a function

this is my code:

```
       var listSongs= {
        nextLink: "",
        collection: ListSongsCollection
      };

     render: function () {
      var view=this;
      listSongs.on("change", function(eventName) {
```

Update, forgot to add my models:

```
var SongModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        title: '',
        image:'',
        id:''

    }

});

var ListSongsCollection= Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: SongModel
});
```

Comment: `listSongs.collection.on`....

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: listSongs.collection.on is not a function same issue

Comment: Probably `$(listSongs.collection).on(...)` What is `ListSongsCollection`? A collection of DOM elements?

Comment: I updated my main post

Comment: because `listSongs` is json object. Could you provide more code for the first bit? Is it a view? Also I guess you can use `listSongs.collection.on` if it is `collection: new ListSongsCollection()` inside `listSongs`

Comment: listSongs is an object how did you got that this is json??? and what it metter if it listSongs or listSongs.collection? this should work on any object, still I tryed 2 option and get same issue. also on my collection I dont think I sould use new because ListSongsCollection is varibal

Comment: You are right, my bad on calling it json object but yes it is object. And no, `on` is not available on any object until and unless you are extending with `Backbone.events`  somewhere. And I don't think why you can't use `new`. Probably an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sameer_kc/P2JR8/41/) would be more clear. Hope it helps

Comment: @Sami is right, you do need to instantiate the collection with `new` to Backbone bind all the events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var listSongs= {
    nextLink: "",
    collection: new ListSongsCollection()
  };

 render: function () {
  var view=this;
  listSongs.collection.on("change", function(eventName) {
```

Comment: this isnt correct becuase your event will be trigger all the times on every add on model need to use regular triger

Comment: I just show you an error. If you want to use custom event name, other then `change`, do it